# Gedit autocomplete plugin c++

Tags: gedit, plugins

Is there a gedit plugin that autocompletes based on c++ frequent words? Or that autocompletes based on a list.

Answer (score 1):

Gedit has *Snippets* plugin:

1. Go to *Preferences* from window menu, *Plugins*, check *Snippets*.
2. Select *Manage Snippets* from window menu and set-up C++.

Test with new *test.cpp* file, enter `main` and click <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will expand to standard main function:

```
int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{

    return 0;
}
```

If it is not enough - you may want to try Geany.